# Error calling Windows Azure ACS with Certificate

Tags: azure

I'm trying to use a client to authenticate to service bus using a certificate and I'm getting the following error -

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"ACS50008: SAML token is invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 40fd75f3-7a9c-490f-9708-8ee24c1b8d6c\r\nCorrelation ID: faaeba2f-4d0e-4b67-a12e-32b9a8006aad\r\nTimestamp: 2013-06-19 11:40:05Z"}

but there's not much detail in there and I can't find anything on the web.

the http request I'm sending is -

```
POST https://[ACS.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13 HTTP/1.1 SB Namespace]

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Host: [ACS SB Namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net

Content-Length: 2902

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive
```

and the SAML token in the body is (decoded for clarity) -

```
<Assertion ID="_71323c38-9f7d-4e34-9681-25ab3338cca4" IssueInstant="2013-06-19T11:58:46.233Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> 
<Issuer>OAuth2SampleX509Identity</Issuer> 
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
<ds:SignedInfo> 
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /> 
<ds:Reference URI="#_71323c38-9f7d-4e34-9681-25ab3338cca4"> 
<ds:Transforms> 
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /> 
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
</ds:Transforms> 
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /> 
<ds:DigestValue>TKIR+dse+tMuZxXCzFO+C7QcCj25xWQ2Uzax1YUmpdQ=</ds:DigestValue> 
</ds:Reference> 
</ds:SignedInfo> 
<ds:SignatureValue>oCP8si[removed for brevity]</ds:SignatureValue> 
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
<X509Data> 
<X509Certificate>[remove for brevity]</X509Certificate> 
</X509Data> 
</KeyInfo> 
</ds:Signature> 
<Subject> 
<NameID>OAuth2SampleX509Identity</NameID> 
<SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer" /> 
</Subject> 
<Conditions NotBefore="0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" NotOnOrAfter="9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"> 
</AudienceRestriction> 
</Conditions> 
</Assertion>
```

I'm testing this using the client from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127795.aspx and believe I have configured ACS following the 
instructions (although I'm using a SB generated ACS namespace, I don't suppose that matters?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this had failed is that the Issuer in the SAML assertion did not match the name of the service identity I was trying to authenticate with

Comment: The issuer is also case sensitive